# Unable to paste value using CTRL-V into field with <p:inputMask> in JSF

Tags: jsf

```
<p:inputMask disabled="#{bean.disabled}" id="InputBox"
    mask="CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" maxlength="40"
        onkeydown="enableSave()" size="40"
                    value="#{Bean.dataObject.value}" />
```

I am unable to paste a value using CTRL-V into this field.How can I rectify this.

Comment: so it works if you remove the 'onkeydown'?

Comment: No it doesn't work even on removal of onkeydown

Answer (score -1):

Remove the maxlength="40"